# Card Style CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I am trying to build a card style collectionViewCell like the one seen in this post

https://medium.com/@phillfarrugia/building-a-tinder-esque-card-interface-5afa63c6d3db

After much searching I found a little bit of code that seems to simulate a card like appearance for a collection view cell

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0,height: 2.0)
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cell.bounds, cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
```

However, when I run the code my cell looks like this

[image]

Looks nothing like a card style UI at all. I can also see the shadow behind so I know something is sort of conflicting. My cell for my code isn't complicated but I have been altering it and not seeing any real change can anyone help me out.

```
import UIKit

class FeaturedEventCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    public var backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
        let firstImage = UIImageView()
        firstImage.clipsToBounds = true
        firstImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        firstImage.image = UIImage(named: "scott_7")
        firstImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        return firstImage
    }()

    @objc func setupViews(){
        setCellShadow()
        addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadows are drawn outside the view, in your case I think they are being clipped by the cell, even though you are setting your masksToBounds to false.

The way I did this was to make the cell and the contentView background clear, and then add another contentView of my own with insets on all side the size of the shadow you want.

I then add my other subviews to this cell.

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

let shadowContentView = UIView( frame:cell.contentView.bounds.insetBy( dx:4.0, dy:4.0)
shadowContentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
shadowContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0.0, height: 2.0)
shadowContentView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
shadowContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
shadowContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
shadowContentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowContentView.backgroundColor = .white 

let firstImageView = UIImageView()
firstImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
firstImageView .layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowContentView.addSubView( firstImageView)
```

Comment: is this being added in cellForItemAt or in the init of the cell

Comment: In the init of the cell

Comment: is insetBy a parameter says it doesnt exist

Comment: It is a method on CGRect, I edited my answer to add in the bounds.